# Equivalence of definitions of projective representations

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetry

There are two definitions of projective representations, which I fail to prove equivalence between:

1. Let $G$ be a group and $\alpha:G \times G \to \mathbb C^{*}$ be a map, which satisfies
   \begin{equation}
   \alpha(g_2,g_3) \cdot \alpha(g_1,g_2g_3)=\alpha(g_1,g_2) \cdot \alpha(g_1g_2,g_3) \; \; \forall g_1,g_2,g_3 \in G.
   \end{equation}
   Then a **projective representation** **of $G$** is a map $T:G \to GL(V)$, such that $T(g) T(h)=\alpha(g,h) T(gh)$. Note that this map need not be a homomorphism.
2. Let $G$ be a group and denote $PGL(V):=GL(V)/(\mathbb C^{*} \cdot \text{id}_{V})$. Then a **projective representation of $G$** is a group homomorphism $\theta:G \to PGL(V)$.

How to show that $2 \implies 1$?

Comment: The cocycle condition in (1) should be multiplication, not addition. What are your thoughts so far? Given $\alpha,T$ in (1) or $\overline{T}$ in (2), do you have any ideas how to define $\overline{T}$ from $T$, or $T$ & $\alpha$ from $\overline{T}$?

Comment: You are right. I will edit. I managed to figure out 1=>2, but 2=>1 I have no idea yet.

Comment: For future reference, the MSE community wants askers to show their ideas and their work, not just allude to them. So you should have just said how you figured out (1)$\Rightarrow$(2).

Comment: Sorry to ask this after the question has been concluded, but: should I close it? I see it has a downvote for not being productive, which I agree with. I will provide more details next time about my work. Or conversely- should I add a detailed answer of my work what I have done?

Comment: I don't think you have the rep to vote to close, let alone unilaterally close. Two other users have voted to close already at the moment. You should just add the work you did and the thoughts you had at the time to your original question. Can't say if the downvote will go away, but your question will no longer be a target of the clean-up crew if you do a good enough job, and possibly earn an upvote or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)$\Rightarrow$(2): Compose $G\xrightarrow{T}\mathrm{GL}(V)\to\mathrm{PGL}(V)$ to get $\overline{T}:G\to\mathrm{PGL}(V)$.

(2)$\Rightarrow$(1): Pointwise pick representatives $T(g)\in\mathrm{GL}(V)$ for $\overline{T}(g)\in\mathrm{PGL}(V)$, arbitrarily. Solve for $\alpha(g,h)$ in the cocycle condition to find how to define $\alpha(g,h)$ in terms of $T$.